# Anyone know about webs.com?

Tags: web-development, html, cms

I have a friend who created a website with web.com which use to be called freewebs.com. He also has his domain name registered through them as well. Are theses one of those dangerous sites to stay away from or is he going to be okay for now?

Answer (score 1):

Back when I first started doing web development and it was solely HTML, CSS, JS, etc I used Webs as my host. They are completely reputable and fine. I even bought my domain from them and a few years later transferred without a problem.

Comment: cool thanks. Hey so is still valuable in our modern time to know hand coding for HTML CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: Of course. I still hand code everything. In fact every web developer I know still does. They may use some tools to take care of the boilerplate, but I don't know a single one that uses anything like Dreamweaver.